# Which web crawler to use to save news articles from a website into .txt files?

Tags: web-crawler

i am currently in dire need of news articles to test a LSI implementation (it's in a foreign language, so there isnt the usual packs of files ready to use).

So i need a crawler that given a starting url, let's say http://news.bbc.co.uk/ follows all the contained links and saves their content into .txt files, if we could specify the format to be UTF8 i would be in heaven.

I have 0 expertise in this area, so i beg you for some sugestions in which crawler to use for this task.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a "Scraper",  and you will have to write one.  Further more you may be in violation of the [BBC's  Terms of Use](http://www.bbc.co.uk/terms/) like anyone cares.

Comment: I just mentioned bbc since everyone knows of it... like i said i need text's in a foreign language so if i find a program that does this i wont be using it in bbc.

Comment: In general scraping can be in violation of a ToS,  idk if this is against the BBC's ToS.   Also stack overflow is only for programming questions.  if you are looking for a program to do everything for you then you should have posted this to SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

you can grab the site with `wget`. Then run it all through some HTML renderer (`Lynx` text browser does the job adequately with `--dump-html` option) to convert HTML to TXT. You will need to write the script to call Lynx on each downloaded file yourself, but that should be easy enough.